# Simplify ArcTan[Tan[t]]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Is there any mechanism in Mathematica to simplify `ArcTan[Tan[t]]` to `t`? The functions `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` leave it as is. When trying to discover relationships, it is useful to consider the arc functions applied to the trig functions as the identity.

Incidentally, `Simplify[Tan[ArcTan[t]]]` evaluates to `t`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need an assumption

```
Simplify[ArcTan[Tan[t]], -π/2 < Re[t] < π/2]
```

> t

Comment: Ah! Thank you! ${}$

Comment: For what it's worth, in this case it also works without the `Re` - `Simplify[ArcTan[Tan[t]], -π/2 < t < π/2]` also works.