# How to find the angle of a rotation matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, geometry, rotation

I know there is post about finding angles of rotation matrix, but all of them required more than a rotation matrix, I want to know that If I have a matrix `m={{cosa,sina}, {-sina,cosa}}`
How should I find the angle a from this rotation matrix?
In that post, someone gave `ArcCos[(Tr[m] - 1)/2] 180/pi`, but it returns a complex number with `i` for some inputs m, which is incorrect.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165353/simplify-arctantant?rq=1

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994780/range-of-inverse-trigonometric-functions-in-mathematica

Comment: "I know there is post" please include a link. "for some inputs m" please say which m. You can edit your question. The formula you give is for [three dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Determining_the_angle). The same formula in two dimensions would be `180/Pi*ArcCos[Tr[m]/2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three rotation matrixs：

```
mat=RotationMatrix/@{π/4,5π/4,7π/4}
```

> [image]

You can get the angle of it:

```
ArcTan@@@mat.{1,0}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming the 2D case:

```
theta[m_?MatrixQ] := PlanarAngle[{0, 0} -> {{1, 0}, m . {1, 0}}]
```

Example:

```
theta[{{Sqrt[3]/2, -(1/2)}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}]
```

> π/6

Answer (score 2):

For the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$, your code computes $\frac{180}\pi\arccos(-\frac12+\cos\theta)$, so strange answers are expected (for instance $\theta=\pi$ yields $\frac{180}\pi\arccos(-\frac32)\not\in\mathbb R$).

If you know  $C=\cos\theta$, you can't solve for $\theta$ uniquely.  Not only is $\theta+2n\pi$ also a solution, but so is $2n\pi-\theta$.  If you know $S=\sin\theta$ you can do better, but still only "mod $2\pi$".

Mathematica doesn't automatically assume this for symbolic arguments.  For instance, Syed's code returns `ArcCos[Cos@t]` when you call it for a general `RotationMatrix@t`.  I tried a lot of combinations of `Assuming,Simplify,Reduce`..., but none of them worked really well.  For numerical inputs, most methods involving inverse trig functions should be fine, just check what the default range of angle output is (i.e. `FunctionRange@ArcCos`).  You'll probably need a conditional +π based on the quadrant.